# How to connect clients with a preset ID on a socket server?

Tags: node.js, sockets

My setup looks like this:

```
Client --> AuthenticationService --> REST-API --> MessageBroker(WebSocket) --> Client(s)
```

When a client is authenticated in the system, it gets a token ID. Now, when any client is changing a value via the REST-API, I want to push this change through websockets to every client BUT the one who changed it.

Therefore I want to filter my `socket.clients[]` through their token IDs.

When I transmit the change, it is easy: I'll just send the token-ID until the REST-API.

> But I need to somehow connect to the socket with the exact same
>   tokenID. How can I accomplish this? Any best practices here?

That's the test client code:

```
(function() {
  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
  const id = 123123

  ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log('websocket is connected ...')

      // sending the id to the socket after connecting
      ws.send('connected', id)
  }
})
```

But now the problem is: How do I know on the socket which message is meant to transport the id and which are the just normal messages?

> I don't want to check EVERY message from the client and see if it's an
>   id message.

**Any help here? What's a good practice to connect clients with a socket with a preset ID?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

When the client is connecting to the websocket, just pass a parameter to the url:

```
const webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080?tokenID=123')
```

In the backend you can get the `tokenID` via `url.parse`:

```
const id = url.parse(req.url, true).query.tokenID
```